# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (UIButton)

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uibutton, option-type

I'm trying to create a button programmatically and add it to a UIScrollView in Swift. The code below is what I am using and throws the infamous "unwrapping optional error" where I add the button as a subview. Why is it doing this? I have checked and compared my code to others' and all seems to look fine.

```
let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
button.frame = CGRectMake(8, 2, 200, 300)
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
button.setTitle(productName, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
self.productButtonView.addSubview(button) //This line throws error
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The as! Operator - developer.apple.com/swift/blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=23)

> Swift 1.2 separates the notions of guaranteed conversion and forced conversion into two distinct operators. Guaranteed conversion is still performed with the`as` operator, but forced conversion now uses the `as!` ... It may be easiest to remember the pattern for these operators in Swift as: `!` implies “this might trap,” while `?` indicates “this might be nil.”

Swift 2 version (Xcode7 beta 2):

```
let button = UIButton(type: .System) as UIButton
// see that the way we do this has changed

button.frame = CGRectMake(8, 2, 200, 300)
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
button.setTitle(productName, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
self.productButtonView.addSubview(button)
```

Swift 1.2 version (Xcode 6.3.2):

```
let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton

button.frame = CGRectMake(8, 2, 200, 300)
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
button.setTitle(productName, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
self.productButtonView.addSubview(button)
```

Comment: Now that I can write in multi-lines with XCode 6.3.2, I realised that it was my "productButtonView" that was nil. Your answer is correct, thank you. Maybe this steps outside the border of this thread, but do I need to do more than just create a UIScrollView (in the storyboard) and connect it to an outlet in order to use it?

Comment: In theory what you are describing should work. So I do not know what to suggest. Assuming that `productButtonView` is definitely a subview of `self` in this context and that the `@IBOutlet` is definitely properly connected. It might be worth starting a new question and posting the entire view controller code + description of the problem to see whether anyone can work out why you are getting a `nil`.

Comment: Worked it out, it wasn't connected for some reason - silly me. Anyhow, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing the first line (as!)

```
 let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
```

Comment: That throws the error: "expected type after 'as'". :(

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using? If you are using older, then write as? i believe. I am using Version 6.3.2 and i get error if i write "as". It must be either "as!" or "as?".

Comment: I'm using XCode version 6.1.1. I tried writing "as?", but that forced me to write a "!" after every time I used the "button" variable, and ended up throwing the same error anyway. Going to switch to 6.3.2.

Comment: Do this check just before you add button to screen.         if let buttonIsOk = button {
            self.view.addSubview(button!)
        } else {
            println("My button is indeed nil!")
        }